# What is the subject of the verb following the comma?

Tags: meaning, subjects, nonfinite-verbs, attachment-ambiguity

This quote is from *Gone with the Wind*, where Scarlett met Rhett Butler at a function to collect for the Confederacy:

> Hot words bubbled to her lips and it was with difficulty that she checked them. There was mockery in everything he said. **She disliked him heartily, lounging there against the booth.** But there was something stimulating about him, something warm and vital and electric.

I think it was Scarlett lounging against the booth, but every translated version I read told me that it was Rhett lounging against the booth.

I thought that in English there can be only one subject in a sentence, but the translator must know English much better than I do.

Plus Scarlett was a widow, so maybe it was indecent for her to be lounging like that.

Comment: There is of course only one subject in a clause. Why can't you simply believe what every translated version says? I too would say that the most plausible answer is that it was Rhett Butler not Scarlett, who was lounging against the booth, in which case "Rhett Butler" is the _understood_ (semantic) subject of the gerund-participial clause.

Comment: It's wrong to say there is only one subject in a sentence: "Bob went to the park and Jill went to the shop" and "I bought a dog, which bit me" are totally legitimate English sentences. As BillJ mentions, there is one subject per clause (whether implied or explicit, composite or single), but sentences can have multiple clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure doesn't give away the meaning. The subject of *standing* could be *her* or could be *him* and you can't tell from the grammar. You hafta recover it from context -- you gotta **guess**, based on what you (think you) know about the characters and their situation. Since this is just a story, there's no evidence or experience except your guesses, so you're on your own.

That's what all the other responses here did -- they figured out how they would have interpreted it, and they mostly agree, as do I, that she meant **he** was standing there. But that's not something that the sentence or the grammar or the meaning tells you. That's something you figure out yourself. Language can only go so far.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot easily picture Scarlet "lounging against a booth", while "hot words bubbled to her lips". The context clearly tells you that it is Rhett that is perceived by Scarlet as "mocking" and "lounging".

As for the grammatical aspect, you can read that sentence as

> She disliked him heartily, [as he was] lounging there against the booth.

Dislike is normally followed by an -ing verb and as [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing) explains:

> Some of these verbs (e.g. can’t *stand, **dislike**, imagine, involve, mind, miss, put off and risk*) **can be used with a new subject before the -ing form** (underlined in the examples below). *If the new subject is a pronoun, it is in the object form (me, **him**, her, us, them)*:
>
> - We just couldn’t imagine **Gerry** singing in public.
> - Do you mind **me** being here while you’re working?

The presence and position of *heartily* may be slightly confusing in the sentence you quote, but the effect is quite strong. It conveys in fewer words the fact that *she hated him heartily* (as he is in general), but also that she felt that hatred *as he was lounging against the booth*, that she hated his attitude.

Comment: And if you drop "heartily" ... *She disliked him lounging there against the booth.*

Answer (score 1):

> *She disliked him heartily,* [*lounging there against the booth*].

We could say it's ambiguous, but I think the most plausible interpretation is that it was the referent of "him" (i.e. Rhett), not Scarlett, who was lounging there against the booth.

Grammatically, the bracketed element is a depictive adjunct giving descriptive information about "him". It is interpreted with progressive aspectuality: "he was lounging there against the booth".

Like most non-finite clauses the gerund-participial (*ing*) clause has no overt subject, but we *understand* it as being "him".